# C++ printing with Diamond of death

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, diamond-problem

first let me explain my hierarchy :

```
        Person
       /     \
   Student Employee
       \     /
       Intern
```

Each class has an `output` function of their own , which prints their data members, and I have to print `Person` only once. The problem is that `Student` and `Employee` are not abstract classes, and people will also make an object of their type, so I can't only call the output function on the `Intern` level.

As you will see in the following code, I've managed to solve this, but I think  this is ugly and not very polymorphic . I've created an additional output function so it will work for all cases. Is there a better way of achieving this ?

```
class Person {
    string name;
    int id;
public:
        virtual void output(ostream& out) {
        out << name << "," << id;
    }
}
```

Student:

```
class Student : virtual public Person {
    string major;
    int year;
public:
    virtual void output(ostream& out) {
        Person::output(out);
        out << "," << major << "," << year;
    }
    virtual void outputStudOnly(ostream& out) {
        out << "," << major << "," << year;
    }
};
```

Employee:

```
class Employee : virtual public Person{
    string jobTitle;
public:
    virtual void output(ostream& out) {
        Person::output(out);
        out << "," << jobTitle;
    }
    virtual void outputEmpOnly(ostream& out) {
        out << "," << jobTitle;
    }
};
```

And Intern :

```
class Intern : public Student, public Employee {
public:
    virtual void output(ostream& out) {
        Person::output(out);
        Student::outputStudOnly(out);
        Employee::outputEmpOnly(out);
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't we just have this, or something similar, which you deleted? And the general answer is only to use inheritance when you absolutely must.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Similar question , had an error not related to this question. This is an assignment from school, I didn't decide on this structure .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you have working code and are looking for improvement suggestions, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @Barmar No, it really isn't off topic. This question is not about improvement suggestions it's about knowing the right way to program ! If this is wrong, I wanna know how and why .

Comment: @Phrancis OK, I thought the custom close reason would kill 2 birds with one stone, instead of having to VTC and also post a comment.

Comment: It's funny how if someone asks "how to do X the proper way" and doesn't show any attempt at all, the top comment is usually "What have you tried?" (implying that OP should always show the solution they came up with, even if they're not satisfied with it), but now when someone actually posted their attempt, the reaction is "since you already have working code, go to CodeReview".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wanted to make the same comment myself, but couldn't express it. I think, you nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That what template method is for. Here is how I would write this code:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    int id;
public:
        void output(ostream& out) {
        out << name << "," << id;
        output_impl(out);
    }
private:
       virtual void output_impl(ostream& ) {}
};

class Student : virtual public Person {
    string major;
    int year;
private:
    virtual void output_impl(ostream& out) {
        out << "," << major << "," << year;
    }

};

class Employee : virtual public Person {
    string jobTitle;
private:
    virtual void output_impl(ostream& out) {
        out << "," << jobTitle;
    }
};

class Intern : public Student, public Employee {
private:
    virtual void output_impl(ostream& out) {
        Student::output_impl(out);
        Employee::output_impl(out);
    }
};
```

And than you call `output` on the object.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for .

Comment: There are no templates in this code, can you explain what you mean by "template method"

Comment: @M.M this term comes from design patterns. While it is language-agnostic, it is usually implemented in C++ as a combination of virtual and nonvirtual functions, i.e. http://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/template.php. Generic pattern definition (Wikipedia quality): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern